# how to make str_detect case insensitive within case_when in r

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a dataframe like below:

```
dfm = data.frame (names = c('email', 'Facebook', 'walmart', 'target', 'instagram', 'costco'))
```

I need to create a new column `source`. When names are facebook, instagram or email, source is media. When names are costco,walmart or target, the source is store.

I use `case_when` and `str_detect`. I need to the `str_detect` to be case insensitive. So below is my code.

```
dfm %>% 
  mutate(source = case_when( str_detect(names, fixed('email|facebook|instagram', ignore_case = T))~'media',
                             str_detect(names, 'walmart|costco|target')~ 'store'))
```

I got:

```
names       source
email       NA          
Facebook    NA          
walmart     store           
target      store           
instagram   NA          
costco      store
```

I do not understand why it did not work. Does anyone know why?

I tried the code below, it returns `TRUE`

```
str_detect('Facebook', fixed('facebook', ignore_case = T))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also try regex instead of fixed:

```
dfm %>% 
  mutate(source = case_when( str_detect(names, regex('email|facebook|instagram', ignore_case = T))~'media',
                             str_detect(names, 'walmart|costco|target')~ 'store'))
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `fixed` it will not recognize `|` as regex. If you want to do exact match use word boundaries i.e `\\b`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dfm %>% 
   mutate(source = case_when(str_detect(names, 
                 regex('\\bemail\\b|\\bfacebook\\b|\\binstagram\\b', 
                        ignore_case = TRUE))~'media',
                  str_detect(names, 'walmart|costco|target')~ 'store'))

#      names source
#1     email  media
#2  Facebook  media
#3   walmart  store
#4    target  store
#5 instagram  media
#6    costco  store
```